# SQL server 2005 XML data import

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I have xml data in a format similar to the below:

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <OrderInfo>mydetails</OrderInfo>
      <orderlines>
        <orderline>
          <orderlineref>1.1</orderlineref>
          <product>myproduct</product>
          <quantity>5</quantity>
        </orderline>
        <orderline>
          <orderlineref>1.2</orderlineref>
          <product>myproduct1</product>
          <quantity>7</quantity>
        </orderline>
      </orderlines>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

I would like to import this into SQL server 2005 using bcp (or any other method really) as long as it runs reasonabbly fast.

How do I go about creating the format file for this type of XML?
Or am I looking in the wrong direction.

So far the only way I have managed to import this data isusing openrowset but it takes way too long.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: [Examples of Bulk Import and Export of XML Documents (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you cast it to xml like :

```
declare @x xml

set @x='<Orders>
  ...
</Orders>'
```

---

or

```
declare @x nvarchar(max)

set @x='<Orders>
  ...
</Orders>'
```

and then :

```
cast (@x as xml)...
```